# Attempt to insert non-property list object with JSON Array

Tags: json, swift

Essentially, I have correctly parsed my data. However, when I'm trying to access the data. It claims that I'm attempting to insert non-propert list object into a UserDefaults Array. How would I be able to convert this somehow to a property list object? Or how would I be able to store the JSON array as a string?

```
var status = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "status") ?? []
struct Response: Codable {
        let weather: [MyResult]
    }
    struct MyResult: Codable {
        let main: String
    }
func getData(from url:String) {
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:url)!, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                return
            }
            // have data
            var result: Response?
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            guard let json = result else {
                return
            }
            print(type(of: json.weather)) // Array
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(json.weather, forKey: "status") // Here is the error
            print(status)
            }).resume()
    }
```

EDIT: When I print status, nothing is there.

```
func getData(from url:String) {
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:url)!, completionHandler: {
            data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("Something went wrong")
                return
            }
            // have data
            var result: Response?
            do {
                result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            guard let json = result else {
                return
            }
            print(type(of: json.weather)) // Array
            do {
                 // Store it with
                let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(json.weather)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "status")
                

                //  Read it
                if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:"status") {
                  let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyResult].self,from:data)
                }
            }
            catch {
               print(error)
            }
            print(status)
            }).resume()
    }
```

Comment: You are storing an array of `MyResult`. This is not JSON. You need to encode it back. And never print meaningless literal strings like `"Something went wrong"` instead of the actual `error`. And in a `Codable` catch block print always `error` rather than `error.localizedDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
do {
     // Store it with  
    let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(json.weather)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "status")

    //  Read it 
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey:"status") {
      let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyResult].self,from:data)
    }  
}
catch {
   print(error)
}
```

Comment: I've tried this code and keep getting the same console "Attempt to insert non property list object" response.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the naming of variables unique so that they don't get confused or mixed up. Here's the cleaned-up code for you.

```
func getData(from url: String) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: url)!) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else {
            if let error = error { print(error) }
            return
        }
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
            print("got response: \(response)")
            let dataToStore = try JSONEncoder().encode(response.weather)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(dataToStore, forKey: "status") // set data to userdefaults
            guard let dataRetrieved = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "status") else { return } // retrieve back weather
            let weather = try JSONDecoder().decode([MyResult].self, from: dataRetrieved)
            print("got weather from user defaults: \(weather)")
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: This did not set anything for key "status" I tried printing it out the next line and for some reason it just says nil. I am only trying to return cloudy, rainy, etc. It shouldn't be this complicated.

Comment: Show what you tried? If you tried the above code exactly it should have worked. What did you get while printing `response` and `weather` from the above code?

Comment: so I tried the exact code above and when I print out the UserDefualts for status I keep getting the default value which I provided. In your print statement "got weather from user..." It prints out the array just fine. However, its setting my userdefaults to a different value that is giving me trouble. When I print out response I get the array of weather and within it "main" which is either sunny etc. I just do not understand why my UserDefault isn't being set properly here.

Comment: I think you're not setting the UserDefaults in the correct format, it needs to be `Data` type and for printing, you've to do exactly what I've done in the above code at the last 3 lines in the do block. If you correct the format of setting and retrieving you should be fine.